segment_anything_fast SamAutomaticMaskGenerator throwing a BackendCompilerFailed-Error
I am trying to set up the SAM-Model from segment_anything_fast by pytorch. I have followed the installation instructions and also added "export SEGMENT_ANYTHING_FAST_USE_FLASH_4=0" as an environment variable.
I have read in an image with cv2 and rand the cv2.cvtColor on it. Now I'm trying to generate masks but every time I run it, I get a BackendCompilerFailed-Error with the following message:
"You can suppress this exception and fall back to eager by setting:
import torch._dynamo
torch._dynamo.config.suppress_errors = True"
Even after setting this to true it throws another error.
My environment looks as follows:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                hd590300_5    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.6.2             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.8.1           py310hc6cd4ac_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
diskcache                 5.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expecttest                0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.53.0                   pypi_0    pypi
fsspec                    2024.6.0                 pypi_0    pypi
hypothesis                6.103.2                  pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.34.1                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        7.1.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.1.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.4             pyh3099207_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.25.0             pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            8.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py310hff52083_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.21.2               h659d440_0    conda-forge
lazy-loader               0.4                      pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 hf3520f5_7    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0              h77fa898_10    conda-forge
libgomp                   13.2.0              h77fa898_10    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.46.0               hde9e2c9_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.2.0              hc0a3c3a_10    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxcrypt                 4.4.36               hd590300_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.3.1                h4ab18f5_1    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.5                  h59595ed_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cublas-cu12        12.1.3.1                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12    12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         8.9.2.26                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cufft-cu12         11.0.2.54                pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-curand-cu12        10.3.2.106               pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cusolver-cu12      11.4.5.107               pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cusparse-cu12      12.1.0.106               pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-nccl-cu12          2.20.5                   pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12     12.5.40                  pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-nvtx-cu12          12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.10.0.84                pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.3.1                h4ab18f5_0    conda-forge
packaging                 24.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       24.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              4.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.47             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.8           py310h2372a71_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pycocotools               2.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.14         hd12c33a_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.10                    4_cp310    conda-forge
pytorch-labs-segment-anything-fast 0.2                       dev_0    <develop>
pyzmq                     26.0.3          py310h6883aea_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.23.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
segment-anything          1.0                       dev_0    <develop>
sentencepiece             0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                70.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sortedcontainers          2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2024.5.22                pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.13          noxft_h4845f30_101    conda-forge
torch                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torchao                   0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.4.1           py310hc51659f_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.14.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
triton                    2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.12.2             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2024a                h0c530f3_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.43.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.5                h75354e8_4    conda-forge
zipp                      3.19.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

Added export SEGMENT_ANYTHING_FAST_USE_FLASH_4=0 as an environment variable.
Updated torch, torchvision and torchaudio to newest versions.
